# JS how to continue event prevent default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, preventdefault

I am trying to pop modal asking the user if he is sure about to leave the page,
while there changes that have not been commited yet.

Those changes are NOT done using a `<form>` element, but just some changes 
that were made on a specific object.

I have tried to detect when he tries to leave the page with either the `$routeChangeStart`
and the `$routeChangeSuccess` like this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ConfirmationModal.fire("Do you sure?", response => {
    if (response) {
      // how to CONTINUE the prevent default??
    }
  });
}
```

The code above actually stop the propgregation and not let the user to leave 
the page.

However - after confirmed the modal, I cannot find any way to continue the page moving.
I mean, I can prevent default but not continue default.

I have tried also to:

`$location.path(PATH)` but this just did not work.

Also - even when user re-click about leaving the page again - the event preventdefault is still 
prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a flag and a conditional:

Something like

```
$scope.allowChange = false;

$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current) {
  // don't do anything when allowChange  === true
  if (!$scope.allowChange) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ConfirmationModal.fire("Do you sure?", response => {
      if (response) {
        $scope.allowChange = true
        $location.path(...) // I forget prop to get new path from
      }
    });
  }

})
```

Comment: Great that works - so the event prevent default will always remain active, until the closure `IF` of it is getting `false`?

BTW, in `next` I have this: `http://localhost:8080/#!/root/settings/permissions`
How to load the next view with this? should I parse only the path and extract it, or that is there anything else?

Comment: As I commented I forget which object has the next path in it. If I remember correctly without going to the docs there is also a `next` argument that has the new path in it. Is outlined in routing docs

Comment: Yes, next provides with the full url

Comment: Doesn't it also have the internal path as well as the full url? If not would be  simple parse to get it from the full one or try `$location.url(fullUrl)`

Comment: Nope. I am using ngRoute if it helps.